# Get fields while updating mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to get field from db while updating it with mongodb.
I have db as;

```
id:1
name: alex
surname: felix
```

What i'm saying is this;

```
db.collection.find({id : 1}, {"name" :1 }).toArray(function(err, result){})
```

returns `{name: alex}`.

But what if I want to get name, while update the same collection.

```
db.collection.update({id : 1}, {$set: {"surname" : "phoenix"}}, function(err, result){})
```

`result` returns the following;

```
{ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 }
```

I want to get `{name: alex}` while I updating. How can I achieve it?

To get `name` field, should I wrote another `find` query? Or can I do it with modifying update query?

Comment: can use `findAndModify` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: Also add set `returnNewDocument` flag to be true, or `new` in mongoose